# How to know that a void runs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, void

want to ask about void type, so I could know that it works or no

in PHP i could have a condition like this:

```
if(mysql_query($query))
{ bla bla }
else
{ print error }
```

how to do like that on ASP.NET?

i'm trying like this:

```
if (k.EditPassword(username.Text, oldPassTxt.Text, newPassTxt.Text) == true )
{
Response.Redirect("sample.aspx");
}
else
{ print error }
```

but of course, it cannot be like that, because void isn't boolean

Comment: Exactly what condition are you trying to handle?

Comment: If something has no flag of success, ideally you should be able to assume that if execution passes through it, it was executed successfully (in other words, if it doesn't throw an exception).  However, depending on who coded it or how trusting you are, that may not be a safe assumption (and it's a rather unpleasant feeling to have to *assume* anything...).

Comment: It's solved, sorry.. I'm really forget about try catch..
now it's work.. my full code:
    EmpWS k = new EmpWS();
            try
            {
                k.EditPassword(username.Text, oldPassTxt.Text, newPassTxt.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex + "Eror");
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually void functions that do work that can fail will have some other way of informing you that they failed.  Often they will throw an Exception:

```
try
{
    k.EditPassword(...)
}
catch(ApplicationException ex)
{
    // print Exception
}
Response.Redirect(...)
```

Other times they will set a status variable or something:

```
k.EditPassword(...)
if (k.Result == Result.OK)
    Response.Redirect(...)
else
    // print error...
```

Looking at documentation or source code for the conditions you are trying to handle is the only way to know how to handle it.

Comment: thanks.. I'm really forget with this try catch condition... this code what i need..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a literal control and add your text to it. So your code will go something like,

```
if (k.EditPassword(username.Text, oldPassTxt.Text, newPassTxt.Text) == true )
{
Response.Redirect("sample.aspx");
}
else
{ Literal1.Text = error; }
```

Literal should be in design file, you can add it from toolbox.

But a better and proper way would be to,

1. Log it. (You would need a log mecahnism)
2. Write a unit test :)